# "Filter by" or "filter according to"?

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering if "filter by" and "filter according to" are both valid, and can be used in the all context or are there exceptions.

ie. Filtering a list of events by venue, or filtering a list of events according to the venue

Thank you.

EDIT:
I always used *by* as in a direct translation from French *filtrer par*; *according to* would be *dépendemment de* ou *en fonction de* which also works, but which one is more "common", or correct in that situation eludes me in English.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please show the research you have already done on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*trier* has another translation of "to sort" in which case "sort by" is much more common than "sort according to". The verb "to filter" has a more passive meaning in which the filtration mechanism mostly sits doing nothing as a liquid or gas passes through it. A similar verb is "to sift"---used for a seperation of powdered or grainy substances. Both "sift" and "filter" are rarely used with "by ..." clauses or "according to...", probably because the apparatus being used is fixed and cannot change how it seperates materials. If you gave an example of context I could suggest a better verb. If you want "filter", the reason a "by..." clause isn't often used with filter is because "by..." clauses with these types of verbs generally take an adjective and imply a seperation by degree, while "filter" implies that everything with a certain property is removed---more of a black-and-white situation. This implies why "filter out..." is so often used.

Comment: But ... in English, *filter* doesn't mean the same thing as *sort* at all. If you *sort* a list, you keep all the elements. If you *filter* a list, you discard some of them (*select* might be a better word.) So how do you know which  meaning of *trier* the OP wants?

Comment: @Peter Shor Yup that's the problem. I assumed *sort* because of the fact that OP wanted a "by" clause. You do have a good point about the more metaphorical uses of "filter" I will add to my answer.

Comment: @BaileyBussiere  I wrote the wrong verb in my OP as I corrected. Shoud've been *filtrer par* and not *trier par*. As for the context, it is a filter on a list of items on a website. Thank you.

Comment: @Eradev In that case, "filter by" is perfect in most cases, but better if it is by a property that has degrees, such as size, weight, or price. I'm assuming you will have many filtration options, probably "filter by..." and then a descending list of properties, in which case "filter by..." is the perfect way to translate it. If it were academic writing it would be a slightly different story. Usually shy away from longer prepositional replacements if a shorter option is available.